iOS widget not updating when selecting SwiftData AppIntent
Swift hobbyist...Feel free to point out how bad the code is.
I'm trying to build a SwiftUI app and I have a SwiftData model called Diem (a countdown event class). The model is linked to DynamicAppIntent in that the user should be able to choose from one of the countdowns in the model to display on the widget.
After much hassle (Fetch from SwiftData model for DynamicAppIntent Widget) the my query finally stopped crashing. However, the widget view is not updating with the selected AppIntent from SwiftData. I think the problem might be with my Provider? I still don't fully understand how timeline works and updates. But it might also still be with my WidgetConfigurationIntent/defaultQuery...
The full project is on GitHub. Some excerpts below:
DiemEntityQuery.swift
struct DiemEntityQuery: EntityQuery, Sendable {
    func entities(for identifiers: [DiemEntity.ID]) async throws -> [DiemEntity] {
        logger.info("Loading diems for identifiers: \(identifiers)")
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Diem.self)
        let modelContext = ModelContext(container)
        let diems = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>(predicate: #Predicate { identifiers.contains($0.name) }))
//        let diems = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>())
        logger.info("Found \(diems.count) diems")
        return diems.map { DiemEntity(from: $0) }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [DiemEntity] {
        logger.info("Loading diems to suggest for specific diem...")
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Diem.self)
        let modelContext = ModelContext(container)
        let diems = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>())
        logger.info("Found \(diems.count) diems")
        return diems.map { DiemEntity(from: $0) }
    }
}

DiemWidgetProvider.swift
private let logger = Logger(subsystem: "Widgets", category: "DiemTimelineProvider")

struct DiemWidgetProvider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    let modelContext = ModelContext(try! ModelContainer(for: Diem.self))  // same issue as Intent
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> DiemWidgetEntry {
//        let diem = try! modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>(sortBy: [.init(\.date)])).first!
        logger.info("Calling placeholder() in DiemWidgetProvider...")
        return DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: .placeholder)
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: DiemWidgetIntent, in context: Context) async -> DiemWidgetEntry {
        let diems = try! modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>(sortBy: [.init(\.date)]))
        logger.info("Found \(diems.count) diems")
        guard let diem = diems.first else {
            return DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: .placeholder)
        }
        return DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: diem)
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: DiemWidgetIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<DiemWidgetEntry> {
        // TODO: update widget once per day

        // Use the selected intent parameter to generate the timeline entry
        if let diemEntity = configuration.diem {
            logger.info("Found configuration diem: \(diemEntity.name)")
            let diem = Diem(entity: diemEntity)
            let entry = DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: diem)
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
            return timeline
        } else {
            // If no diem is selected, provide a placeholder or default entry
            let diems = try! modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Diem>(sortBy: [.init(\.date)]))
            logger.info("No diem selected. Providing placeholder to widget...")
            logger.info("Found \(diems.count) diems")
            guard let diem = diems.first else {
                logger.info("Using placeholder diem as placeholder")
                return Timeline(
                    entries: [DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: .placeholder)],
                    policy: .never
                )
            }
            logger.info("Using first diem as placeholder...")
            return Timeline(entries: [DiemWidgetEntry(date: .now, diem: diem)], policy: .atEnd)
        }
    }
}

